finding a vector basis and complete solution to differential equations
I'm studying the chapter on basis vectors in Strang's "Intro to Linear Algebra" and am stuck on a question about the basis and complete solution of a differential equation. Here's the question:
(a) Find a basis for all solutions to
$$\frac{d^4y}{dx^4} = y(x)$$
(b) Find a particular solution, then a complete solution to
$$\frac{d^4y}{dx^4} = y(x) + 1$$
For (a), my basis is
$$y=\cos x$$
$$y=\sin x$$
$$y=e^x$$
$$y=e^{ix}$$
but I'm stuck on how to proceed with (b)
Do I find nullspace by setting $x$ or $y(x)$ equal to $0$ ?
$$\frac{d^4y}{dx^4} -1 = 0$$
or
$$\frac{d^4y}{dx^4} -1 = y(0)$$
I can see the first is true when $$y(0)= \cos(0)$$
$$y(0)=e^0$$ $$y(0)=e^{i0}$$
but am really unsure how to proceed and can't imagine any solution that solves
$$\frac{d^4y}{dx^4} = y(x) + 1$$.

Did you find a particular solution to (b)?

One approach is to notice that if $y$ satisfies the (b), then $\frac{d^5y}{dx^5} = {dy \over dx}$, so you can use the homogenous equation approach to find a family of solutions that will contain the solution to (b). Then use some trickery to find the complete solution.

error, once you include $\sin x$  and $\cos x$  you cannot use $e^{-x}.$  The final pair could be $e^x$  and $e^{-x},$  or the convenient pair $\sinh x$ and $\cosh x$  Finally, one solution for $y'''' = 1+y$  is constant function $y = -1.$

So, the particular solution is $y(x)=-1$ and the complete solution is $y(x)=-1+\cos {(x)} + \sin {(x)} + e^x + e^{ix}$?

Or rather, one can scale the nullspace solutions so is it actually $y(x)=-1+c_1\cos {(x)} + c_2\sin {(x)} + c_3e^x + c_4e^{ix}$?

The solution for
$$
\frac{d^4y}{dx^4} = y(x)
$$
after inspection into the characteristic operator equation $s^4-1 = (s^2+1)(s^2-1) = (s-i)(s+i)(s-1)(s+1)=0$ the solution is given by
$$
y(x) = \cases{
a_1 e^{-ix}+a_2e^{ix}+a_3e^{-x}+a_4 e^x \ \ \text{or}\\
b_1 \sin x+b_2\cos x+ b_3 e^x + b_4 e^{-x}\ \ \text{or}\\
c_1 \sin x+c_2\cos x+ c_3\sinh(x) + c_4\cosh(x)
}
$$
all equivalents. Note that $\{\sin x, \cos x\}$ can be obtained as linear combinations of $\{e^{-ix}, e^{ix}\}$ as well as $\{\sinh x,\cosh x\}$ from $\{e^{-x}, e^x\}$. Now considering
$$
\frac{d^4y}{dx^4} = y(x)+1
$$
defining $z(x) = y(x)+1$ we have equivalently
$$
\frac{d^4z}{dx^4} = z(x)
$$
then
$$
z(x) = d_1 \sin x+d_2\cos x+ d_3 e^x + d_4 e^{-x}
$$
and
$$
y(x) + 1 = d_1 \sin x+d_2\cos x+ d_3 e^x + d_4 e^{-x}
$$

Thanks for the answer.  Is there a reason that $e^{ix}$, $\cosh {(x)}$ or $\sinh {(x)}$ should not be considered a part of the solution?

Please. See edited explanations.

Wow, thank you.  I was not aware of the trig functions relationship to e, but just started researching. This is a lot to learn and ponder.
